# Kafka State Store Processor Delete: how to use?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've defined a class extending *Processor* and I'm using a *KeyValueStore* to store temporary store some messages before to send them to the sink topic. In particular, I receive on a source topic a set of fragmented messages and, once all are received, I've to assemble them and send, the concatenated message to the sink topic. In the `Processor:process()` method, once I've sent the message with the *forward()* I want to delete, by means of the *[delete(K key)](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/KeyValueStore.html#delete(K))* method, the message from the state store. 
In the processor I've created the state store with

`StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<byte[], String>> storeBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("message-store"), Serdes.ByteArray(), Serdes.String());`

The problem is that the removal does not happen and when I send another message with the same key, I still receive in the *value* the previous messages.

Code:

`kvStore = (KeyValueStore<byte[], String>) this.context.getStateStore("message-store");`

`kvStore.delete((byte[]key)`

The `put` and the `get` of the state store work properly.

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: I've "partially" solved by setting to `null` the stored value but I would like to use the `delete` indeed.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to use the `delete`?